# Regexp for word starting with char but not ending with that char

Tags: regex

I want to find in a string sequences between spaces starting with @ but not ending with it. Ie find @keyword but not @something@. For example

```
"@hello how are @you? I am @good, thank @you! But @bad@ is not okay."
```

should match "hello", "you", "good", "you" but not bad

Me and GPT4 think that this should work but it doesn't

```
/@[^\s]+(?<!@)/
```

neither this and some other combinations

```
/@[a-zA-Z0-9_]+(?<![@\s])/
```

Comment: Do you want to also get `foo` from `abc@foo.com`? Are the characters to the right of `@` word only characters or can there be any other symbols? Say, `@abc!@`, do you need `abc!` from it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering your example strings contain word only characters you can use

```
(?<=@)\w+\b(?!@)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mac08G/2).

*Details*:

- `(?<=@)` - a positive lookbehind that requires a `@` char immediately to the left of the current location
- `\w+` - one or more word characters
- `\b` - a word boundary (it will stop the engine from backtracking into `\w+` pattern if the subsequent lookahead check fails and we won't get any match if the substring like `@abc@` is found)
- `(?!@)` - a negative lookahead disallowing a `@` char immediately to the right of the current location.

Answer (score 2):

You may use this regex with a negative lookahead:

```bash
@[^@\s]+\b(?!@)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/qQrKTb/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `@`: Match a `@`
- `[^@\s]+`: Match 1+ of any character that are not `@` and not whitespace
- `\b`: Word boundary
- `(?!@)`: Negative lookahead to assert that next character is not a `@`

Answer (score 1):

> I want to find in a string sequences between spaces starting with @
> but not ending with it

Apparently you also want to match only word characters, in that case you might use `\w`

```
@(?<=(?<!\S@))\w+(?!\S*@(?!\S))
```

- `@(?<=(?<!\S@))` Match @ and assert a whitspace boundary before it
- `\w+` match 1+ word chars
- `(?!\S*@(?!\S))` Assert that the "word" does not end with @

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/8ggnlL/1)